# How do I set Input interface is output interface

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables

I have eth0 with IP X.X.X.X and eth0:0 with IP Y.Y.Y.Y.

My goal is if I connect to eth0 then output ip shoud be X.X.X.X and if I connect to eth0:0 the output ip should be Y.Y.Y.Y.

Example:

VPN client connect to eth0(IP X.X.X.X) -> IP X.X.X.X

VPN client connect to eth0:0(Y.Y.Y.Y) -> IP Y.Y.Y.Y

VPN client connect to eth0:1(ZX.ZX.ZX.ZX) -> IP ZX.ZX.ZX.ZX

VPN client connect to eth0:2(ZY.ZY.ZY.ZY) -> IP ZY.ZY.ZY.ZY

VPN client connect to eth0:3(ZA.ZA.ZA.ZA) -> IP ZA.ZA.ZA.ZA

Right now its always X.X.X.X

I tried iptables but its not working..

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

ip_forward is 1

ALso tried ip route

I think the right way is to set it with route?

Comment: are you able to re-word this more clearly ? It dosen't make a whole lot of sense at the moment. Do you mean you're trying to ping one interface from the other one ?

Comment: better. i think the confusion is 'i should see' - which is pretty vague. See where ? As the ip address given to the client ? That wouldn't make sense as you can't have a client with the same ip as the vpn server.

Comment: Ohhh I see, you right! I changed it. The goal is that if I call website A then it should give me the right output IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to BB.BB.BB.BB
```

BB.BB.BB.BB = source IP

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

You need masquerading (NAT) for the vpn clients. Something like:

`iptables -A POSTROUTING -s (subnet of vpn clients) -j MASQUERADE`

if your vpn server assigns clients to 192.168.1.0/24 for instance, put that as the -s argument.

Comment: >iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s  -j MASQUERADE
Bad argument `MASQUERADE'

Comment: sorry, superuser ate my angle brackets.

Comment: I wish it would work but I still see the ip from eth0. With 'iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 1.2.3.4 -j MASQUERADE' ip 1.2.3.4 is obfuscated

Comment: even did: ip route add 1.2.3.4 via 1.2.3.4 dev eth1

Comment: i dont think i understand your setup enough to give you the exact commands. But assuming you're routing traffic from the client over the vpn link (which you may or may not be currently, depending on the client's routing table), and you've got masquerading on, it'll work.

Comment: What exactly do you need to know? I will provide

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the default route, not anything to do with iptables. If you want to switch your default gateway then run these commands:

```
ip -4 route del default
ip -4 route add default via <gateway ip> dev <interface>
```

The gateway IP is the gateway or router for that interface's subnet. So, if eth1 is on Y.Y.Y.Y and netmask is 255.255.255.0, the gateway needs to be on the same subnet (e.g. something on Y.Y.Y.*). You can only have one default gateway at a time unless you are using a specialized setup.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense, but what if I have 10 ips? eth1, eth2, etc.?

Comment: I actually have eth0, eth0:0, eth0:1 etc. 'ip -4 route add default via XX.XX.XX.XX dev eth0:0' always defaults to eth0

Comment: Even if you have 10 interfaces with 10 different IP addresses, the answer is the same: You will still only be able to use one default gateway through one interface at a time. As far as I know, using a virtual interface (eth0:0, eth0:1, etc.) works fine with the `ip` command, but maybe it treats eth0:0 as equivalent to eth0. I'm not really sure.